# IF inside an action="" - different method based on criteria

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I'm struggling with syntax here.

This is what I'm trying to do - obviously the syntax is wrong.

```
<apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!IF(x=1, {!save}, {!otherMethod})}"
```

How would I format the {!action}'s in the above line for it to work?

Comment: I think you need to use Javascript to determine which action method to be invoked. Do you need a example for that?

Comment: Hm.  The javascript route would work quite well.    Can you call javascript from an "Action="?  I thought you can only call JS from "onchange/onclick/ondblclick" etc.

Comment: You are correct. We cannot call javascript from `action` property.

Comment: That was my issue.  I already had JS triggered on the "oncomplete", but I wanted an action ran before that depending on some criteria... which I just realized I could have done that in the JS anyways, and just used an empty dummy method in the "action="" for the apex actionsupport.  Thanks for feedback, helped me realize what I should have done!

Comment: I think the another option as mentioned by Boris in the comments is to have a delegated action method on the controller which does the conditional check before calling the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{! }` is the markup for the expression, once you're in, there is no need to add another expression, everything inside is going to be evaluated. Try `{!IF(x = 1, save(), otherMethod())}`. I haven't tried this with the `action` parameter and methods, but in general that's how it works.

Alternatively, you can have 2 separate `<apex:actionsupport />` tags and render them conditionally:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!x = 1}">
    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!x != 1}">
    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!otherMethod}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Hey Boris, thanks for the quick Reply!  I'm getting a "Unknown function save.  check spelling" error.  It definitely IS called save - "public void save()" - thoughts?

Comment: Maybe try just 'save' without the brackets in VF?

Comment: I've tried that too, various variations.  I'm trying the two different action supports now actually.

Comment: @BorisBachovski, Actually I tried with a sample page and looks like we cannot have `IF` condition for `action` property or may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: That could be the case. As I said I haven't tried with action. In that case, the other option with having 2 separate tags should be the way to go.

Comment: Hey Boris - it didn't work in my case since I need this to trigger on change of a SelectRadio, which the action support is embedded.  I'm sure it would work in another scenario.  I'm going to just use apex:PARAM to pass a value to a another method which will trigger the right method based on the value.  Thanks for your feedback and help!

Comment: Yeah that is something that will definitely work. Have a delegate method that will call a subsequent method based on the passed in parameter ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the expression symbol only once at the beginning.. and all the following conditions and values doesn't need the expression symbol again.

```
<apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!IF(x=1, save(), otherMethod())}"/>
```

Comment: You beat me to it! :)

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't work actually.